# How to separate the result Python web scraping data with a comma

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull data and information from different sites. I worked on a script it works well, however, when I try to print the result there is some problems like the results are like sentences there is no comma no delimiter. Nothing I tried myself and nothing.

This is the site i am working on http://www.conditions-de-banque-tunisie.com/banques-en-tunisie.html

I have tried to put a comma between results and nothing. The comma comes at the end, that's all.

```
linksname.find_all('p')[i].text + ','
```

```py
import requests
import bs4
import csv
import io
response = requests.get('http://www.conditions-de-banque-tunisie.com/banques-en-tunisie.html')
response.status_code
soup_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup_obj.prettify()


#print('shhh') 
linksname = soup_obj.find(class_='bloc-banques-liste')
#linksname.text
textContent = []
for i in range(0,1): links =   linksname.find_all('p')[i].text
textContent.append(links)  
for text in textContent: 
    print('----------------------------')
    print(text)
    with io.open("fname.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f: f.write(text)
```

This is the result :

> North Africa International BankAdresse : Avenue Kheireddine Pacha Ennassim Montplaisir 1002 TUNISTé : +216 71 950 800Fax : +216 71 950 840Site web :  http://www.naibbank.com/
>
> Qatar National BankAdresse : Rue de la cité des sciences - B.P. 320 - 1080 Tunis CedexTé : +216 71 750 000Fax : +216 71 235 611Site web :  http://www.qnb.com.tn/

I expect that the result will be like :

> North Africa International Bank  , Adresse : Avenue Kheireddine Pacha Ennassim Montplaisir 1002 , TUNISTé : +216 71 950 800 , Fax : +216 71 950 840 ,Site web :  http://www.naibbank.com/

Or just the best results is:

> North Africa International Bank , venue Kheireddine Pacha Ennassim Montplaisir 1002 , +216 71 950 800 , +216 71 950 840 , :  http://www.naibbank.com/

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below, at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below and let me know if that helps.

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv
import io
response = requests.get('http://www.conditions-de-banque-tunisie.com/banques-en-tunisie.html')
response.status_code
soup_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup_obj.prettify()


#print('shhh') 
linksname = soup_obj.find(class_='bloc-banques-liste')
textContent = []
links = linksname.findChildren("div", class_='banques-liste-desc', recursive=True)
links = [" \n ".join([y.text for y in link.findChildren("p")]) for link in links]
print(str(links))
```

Comment: thank you but there is a little probleme the result is good but it's like a big paragraph not like blocs can you update ur code please because the result i am going to put them in a csv and with that result i can't

Answer (score 0):

The following is a  somewhat simplified version of your code, but it should get you to where you need to be, after fitting it to your own style:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.conditions-de-banque-tunisie.com/banques-en-tunisie.html')

soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")

textContent = []
linksname = soup.find(class_='bloc-banques-liste')
for name in linksname:
    entry =   linksname.find_all('p')[0].text
    textContent.append(entry) 
    break

for bank in textContent:
    print(bank.replace(' :',',').strip())
```

Output:

```
Al BarakaAdresse, 88, Avenue Hedi Chaker 1002 TunisTé, +216 71 790 000Fax, +21671 780 235Email, contact@albarakabank.com.tnSite web,  http://www.albarakabank.com.tn/ 



Amen BankAdresse, Avenue Mohamed V 1002 Tunis - TunisieTé, (+216) 71 148 000Fax, (+216) 71 833 517Site web,  http://www.amenbank.com.tn/
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "bloc-banques-liste" class to find objects you can use "banques-liste-desc"
This will directly give you the list of all blocks.
Check following code.

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv
import io
response = requests.get('http://www.conditions-de-banque-tunisie.com/banques- 
en-tunisie.html')
response.status_code
soup_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup_obj.prettify()

linksname = soup_obj.find_all(class_='banques-liste-desc')
for i in range(0, len(linksname)):
    name = linksname[i].find('h1').find('a').text
    print(name)
    address = linksname[i].find_all('p')
    for j in range(0, len(address)):
        print(address[j].text)
    print("----------------------------")
```

Here I have printed all the values separately, instead of that you can directly join them using comma.